# Unable to run Cypress on Ubuntu 20 (WSL)

Tags: ubuntu, cypress, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Unable to run `cypress 4.12.0` on Ubuntu 20 (WSL)

I'm receiving this error:

```
Cypress cannot run because this binary file does not have executable permissions here:

/home/****/.cache/Cypress/4.12.0/Cypress/Cypress

Reasons this may happen:

- node was installed as 'root' or with 'sudo'
- the cypress npm package as 'root' or with 'sudo'

Please check that you have the appropriate user permissions.

----------

Platform: linux (Ubuntu - 20.04)
Cypress Version: 4.12.0
```

I'm not experienced Linux user.
I have tried to reinstall cypress and node - nothing helped.

I tried [this solution](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6516), but I'm unable to to find `Cypress.app`. Seems that `/Users/***/Library/Caches/Cypress/4.0.2/Cypress.app/Contents/MacOS/Cypress` is obsolete path

Comment: Did you install node or Cypress using sudo, by chance? Also the solution and link you referenced is specifically for MacOS and you are using Ubuntu on Windows correct?

Comment: Yes, on windows. Frankly, I dont remember whether I used `sudo` or not. What is the correct way? with sudo?

Comment: you don't want to use sudo when installing node or any npm package. That can cause all kinds of issues. You might want to try and reinstall node and npm and make sure you don't use sudo.

Comment: @robertguss thanks, I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I should have to install `nx` with this command: `npm i -g @nrwl/cli`